# selenium.windowfocus() what is this command used for?

Tags: selenium

what is this command for?

Answer (score 10):

You might think that Selenium.selectWindow() would be all you need. But that simply tells Selenium which window you want all the Selenium commands to go to. One of the commands you can send to it is "give this (currently selected) window focus".

It's a bit confusing, because Windows (and other systems) sometimes refer to the "selected window" - the one that's on top of the others, or the "active" window. Here, we call it the window that "has focus". It's the window where keyboard events will be directed. Inside a window, individual widgets (text fields, scroll bars, buttons) can have focus too.

So windowFocus() is like clicking on the title bar of the window that Selenium is currently working with.

Answer (score 4):

From the Selenium Documentation

> **windowFocus()**
>
> Gives focus to the currently selected
>   window

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, getting window focus using the Selenium windowFocus() method is sometimes not effective.  I find myself sometimes using a JavascriptExecutor,  then use the Selenium switchTo() method to switch to the handle that needs focus and then execute :

```
public static void getWindowFocus( String windowHandle ) {
   driver.switchTo( windowHandle );
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
    js.executeScript( "window.focus();" );
    js = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless or until, you are using windowHandles to switch between multiple windows, ur focus will be default on first windows launched by selenium. widnowFocus does the same thing